# I want to stop real-time data reflection from the firebase in angular-2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

When I changes in database value then its reflect in my page without refresh. So I want to stop real time data reflection.

```
constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase,
    public route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.addemployee = af.list('/employees');
    this.employee = af.object('/employees');
}

getEmployees() {
    this.employees = this.af.list('/employees') as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    return this.employees;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
Adding `take(1)` so the line is `this.employees = this.af.list('/employees').take(1) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;`

If I understand you correct. You don't want realtime updates but only the data one time.

You are probably using: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on
this is what gives you data updates.

```
ref.on('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  // ...
});
```

If you only want the data one time, you can use: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once

```
// Basic usage of .once() to read the data located at ref.
ref.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    // handle read data.
  });
```

Update: Added very simple JavaScript example, request from comment.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('database/path/to/something');
ref.once('value')
  .then(function(dataSnapshot) {
    // handle read data.
    let data = dataSnapshot.val();
    // data is { "name": "Ada", "age": 36 }
    // data.name === "Ada"
    // data.age === 36
  });
```

Comment: "stil editing this 2 sec" I dont know Angular2, i just know it is JavaScript, here is JavaScript example.

Comment: ohh.. But I want to in angular2

Comment: try this: this.employees = this.af.list('/employees').take(1) as FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;